# Xamarin Forms Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a Xamarin.Forms app that uses Firebase messaging. I'm following the documentations but when I am adding the Nuget packages and deploy my app to my Android device I get the following error:

> Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'No static method checkBuilderRequirement(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)V in class Ldagger/internal/Preconditions; or its super classes (declaration of 'dagger.internal.Preconditions' appears in /data/app/com.technologygate.golden-1/base.apk)'

Anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I installed the latest Xamarin.Google.Dagger NuGet package into my Xamarin.Android instance and that seems to have fixed it for me. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Brilliant, I think that might be the solution. I downgraded to an older version and the solution was same as yours downloading a missing package. Weird they have to fix this issue..

Comment: Yup that was the problem.. Thank you again

Comment: Thank you @Danny, I got this same issue today and just follow your recommendation to fix it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Solved. Another dependency problem....Xamarin is such a pain